# How Do You POST JSON Data In PHP? (Convert Raw cURL Code Into PHP)

Tags: php, curl

I am working with Facebook's API, and I'm trying to conduct a cURL request in PHP.

This request is a POST request and passes some JSON data.

I want this JSON data to be an array within PHP, then pass this into the cURL request.

Here is an example cURL request from FB's documentation.

```
curl -X POST \
  -F 'data=[
       {
         "event_name": "PageView",
         "event_time": 1610378833,
         "user_data": {
           "fbc": "fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890",
           "fbp": "fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397",
           "em": "309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd"
         }
       }
     ]' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<PIXEL_ID>/events
```

I have tried multiple attempts in PHP, but my array doesn't seem to be parsed correctly.

Here is my PHP Code:

```
$data = array("data" => array("event_name" => "Purchase", "event_time" => time()),

        "access_token" => "EAADZAQ7wNP3UBAMjOcHJV1dvgRYPoyarnLPO5Rr6cwRiOuF0biRTZCJWbCn000U9SD8hovXoKZB0zg1H8PoTI3d4RuvUZC1VQshieXSPcZABiCwqi1rgzzaYZBfMkD6qgAZBKikCtG3jO9SYWanuPUvctypbyoxQm4zVI5Cq8K"

);          

$dataString = json_encode($data);                                         
                                                                                                                    
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/229975271636842/events');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataString))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                                                                       
echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here is the error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) param data must be an array.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"ACWsWbLVtlLZdbMyty_9VKA"}}
```

Here is [Facebook's Documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/using-the-api)

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please paste your code so that we can see what's probably wrong in it?

Comment: Can you link to this documentation please? `data=` makes it not valid JSON as far as I can see. But yeah we'll need to see your PHP code (and any errors it generates) so we can help you fix it. Don't try and call command-line curl from PHP, just sort out the problem with your syntax instead.

Comment: P.S. This: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ would likely help you convert this code to the PHP equivalent

Comment: I have updated my question with my code and error.

Comment: Why not use Facebooks PHP SDK, such that you don't have to write such stuff by hand?

Comment: If that's your actual access token in the PHP code you posted, you might want to revoke it

Comment: I need a custom solution that will use a cURL proxy, isolating my server. The FB PHP API may track my server and this is not what I want.

Comment: @iainn I'm not that silly!! I edited those values :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, you don't need to json_encode the data.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$array = [
    "data" => [[
        "event_name"=> "PageView",
        "event_time"=> 1610378833,
        "user_data" => [
            "fbc" => "fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890",
            "fbp" => "fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397",
            "em" => "309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd"
        ]
    ]]
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/229975271636842/events',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($array),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The next error I get is this: {"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter data is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AaAL9rH-QdzK0QVvar1Rh0f"}}

Comment: @JackTrowbridge I have updated the code, this code runs but has a permission issue for your API, confirm please

Comment: It works thank you! It was in combination with Emanuele Gandolfi's answer.

Comment: Added the array config, also make sure access-token is sent in the header and not the post body

Comment: Your solution does not take into account the access token. If you add this in the array and also thumbs up Emanuele Gandolfi answer, then I will accept yours as the answer.

Comment: I would not add access token here anyway, and would even ask you to remove it from the question, leaves a bad impression on newbies that it's fine to paste tokens.

Comment: I edited my values, but I do understand your point. Emanuele Gandolfi needs some love too. So I can't accept your answer until you upvote his.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that an array is missing. The "data" field is an array with an object inside.
Try this:

```
$data = array( // main object
    "data" => array( // data array
        array("event_name" => "Purchase", "event_time" => time()), // single data array entry
    ),
    "access_token" => "..."
);
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Comment: @JackTrowbridge You're welcome! If it's working please accept my answer :)

Comment: It's very difficult to choose, Ashu was here first and did help with the first bit. I will make him thumbs up to your answer before I accept his. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = [
        "event_name"=> "PageView", 
        "event_name2"=> "PageView2",
        // and so on ...
];
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array) );

$data = ['data'=> $object];
```

and then pass it to your curl function.

For Nico. Right. I forgort explanation: I think:

```
-F 'data=[
       {
```

means Object inside array. And the FB Error Response tell us: "error":{"message":"(#100) param data must be an array. And Jack encode the whole data to a datastring.

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/jack/public_html/FBCAPI/test2.php on line 27

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: What's the point in encoding and then immediately decoding the array?

Comment: @iainn that's what I thought...

Comment: What Gandolfi wrote: "The "data" field is an array with an object inside." Take a look   -F 'data=[
       { 

means object inside array. not more.

Comment: Thanks for your input :)